# Find duplicate combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, aggregate-functions

I need a query to find duplicate combinations in these tables:

AttributeValue:

```
 id | name
------------------
  1 | green
  2 | blue
  3 | red
  4 | 100x200
  5 | 150x200
```

Product:

```
 id | name
----------------
 1  | Produkt A
```

ProductAttribute:

```
 id | id_product | price
--------------------------
  1 |          1 |   100
  2 |          1 |   200
  3 |          1 |   100
  4 |          1 |   200
  5 |          1 |   100
  6 |          1 |   200
  7 |          1 |   100   -- duplicate combination
  8 |          1 |   100   -- duplicate combination
```

ProductAttributeCombinations:

```
 id_product_attribute | id_attribute
-------------------------------------
                    1 |           1
                    1 |           4
                    2 |           1
                    2 |           5
                    3 |           2
                    3 |           4
                    4 |           2
                    4 |           5
                    5 |           3
                    5 |           4
                    6 |           3
                    6 |           5
                    7 |           1
                    7 |           4
                    8 |           1
                    8 |           5
```

I need SQL that creates result like:

```
id_product | duplicate_attributes
----------------------------------
         1 | {7,8}
```

Comment: Could you explain why 7+8 (both have price 100) are duplicates, but for example 3+5 (both also have price = 100) are not duplicates ?

Comment: 7+8 are duplicates because have same attributes such as 1 and 2. 7 === 1 and 8 === 2. (Table ProductAttributeCombinations)

Comment: Any reason you want `{7,8}` reported and not `{1,2}` or even `{1,2,7,8}`? And what's the role of `id_product` in this? Do you only want to identify *duplicate instances of the same product* (with the same set of attributes)? So that the same set of attributes would not qualify as duplicate if the connected `id_product` is different? Or just duplicates for a *given* `id_product`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, 7 is a duplicate of 1 and 8 is a duplicate of 2.  As phrased, your question is a bit confusing, because 7 and 8 are not related to each other and the only table of interest is `ProductAttributeCombinations`.

If this is the case, then one method is to use string aggregation

```
with combos as (
      select id_product_attribute,
             string_agg(id_attribute::text, ',' order by id_attribute) as combo
      from ProductAttributeCombinations pac
      group by id_product_attribute
    )
select *
from combos c
where exists (select 1
              from combos c2
              where c2.id_product_attribute > c.id_product_attribute and
                    c2.combo = c.combo
             );
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. 7 is duplicate of 1 and 8 is duplicate of 2. But your SQL makes error: ERROR:  column c2.combos does not exist

Comment: @user3249421 . . . `c.combos` didn't exist either.  I put in the column alias.

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves some room for interpretation. Here is my educated guess:

***For each product, return an array of all instances with the same set of attributes as any other instance of the same product with smaller ID.***

```
WITH combo AS (
   SELECT id_product, id, array_agg(id_attribute) AS attributes
   FROM  (
      SELECT pa.id_product, pa.id, pac.id_attribute
      FROM   ProductAttribute            pa
      JOIN   PoductAttributeCombinations pac ON pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id
      ORDER  BY pa.id_product, pa.id, pac.id_attribute
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT id_product, array_agg(id) AS duplicate_attributes
FROM   combo c
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   combo
   WHERE  id_product = c.id_product
   AND    attributes = c.attributes
   AND    id < c.id
   )
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Sorting can be inlined into the aggregate function so we don't need a subquery for the sort ([like @Gordon already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33720146/939860)). This is shorter, but also typically slower:

```
WITH combo AS (
   SELECT pa.id_product, pa.id
        , array_agg(pac.id_attribute ORDER BY pac.id_attribute) AS attributes
   FROM   ProductAttribute            pa
   JOIN   PoductAttributeCombinations pac ON pac.id_product_attribute = pa.id
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT ...
```

This only returns products with duplicate instances.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73aa3/1)

Your table names are rather misleading / contradict the rest of your question. Your sample data is not very clear either, only featuring a *single* product. I assume there are many in your table.

It's also unclear whether you are using double-quoted table names preserving CaMeL-case spelling. I assume: no.